# Julia: Problems with Adding Packages (BinDeps)

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia's package manager, and I am having trouble installing GLPK and LinProgGLPK.
 I have already run `Pkg.Init()` and have successfully installed Curl using `Pkg.add("Curl")`. However, when I try to install GLPK or LinProgGLPK (using `Pkg.add("GLPK")` and `Pkg.add("LinProgGLPK"))`, I get the following message:

```
MESSAGE: Installing BinDeps v0.0.0
ERROR: Path BinDeps already exists! Please remove to allow installation.
 in _resolve at pkg.jl:345
 in anonymous at no file:163
 in cd at file.jl:26
 in cd_pkgdir at pkg.jl:42
 in add at pkg.jl:143
 in add at pkg.jl:175
```

I seem to get the same message for other packages that are dependent on BinDeps (including Winston).

I have tried calling `Pkg.rm("BinDeps")`, `Pkg.add("BinDeps")`, `Pkg.update()`, and `Pkg.resolve()`, and then returned to trying to add GLPK, but the same message persists. I have also entered `~/.julia` to remove the BinDeps folder, but that did not work either. What am I missing?

P.S. I am running julia in Linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, when something gets screwed up, it's best just to wipe ~/.julia and re-add the packages.

Just make sure you back up your local changes!

Comment: Actually, I did that, and the same thing happened. I even tried re-installing Julia itself, with no change.

Comment: I figured out the problem: an error in the installation of a package (e.g. BinDeps or GLPK) terminates the installation, yet Julia doesn't acknowledge this; therefore the package is in a limbo between installed and uninstalled where it can neither be added nor removed. The only solution that I have found is to wipe ~/.julia as WestleyArgentum said.

Comment: There are kinks, but the package manager is really young and getting better all the time :/

Comment: I'm reinstalling for maybe the 12th times.