# DataFrames package functions using wrong types?

Tags: julia

I installed the DataFrames package using JuliaStudio, with no problems. Then I tried to replicate the simple example [here](http://juliastats.github.io/DataFrames.jl/io.html) using the following code

```
using DataFrames
cd("my local directory here")
readtable("maindata.csv")
```

and got this error:

```
no method readtable!
(ParsedCSV,IOStream,Int64,ParseOptions{ASCIIString,UTF8String})
```

In the packages folder, I opened the file [io.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/blob/master/src/io.jl) and saw the types that readtable! is expecting don't match what is shown in the error above.

```
function readtable!(p::ParsedCSV,
                    io::IO,
                    nrows::Int,
                    o::ParseOptions)
```

So I changed the second and third types in the `readtable!` definition to `IOStream` and `Int64`, respectively to match what the error above was showing. Then I tried to run

```
readtable("maindata.csv")
```

again, and got the same error, but for a different function:

```
no method readnrows!
(ParsedCSV,IOStream,Int64,ParseOptions{ASCIIString,UTF8String})
```

How can I get the function `readtable()` to read my file successfully without needing to edit the types in all the package functions?

Comment: What version of Julia Studio are you on, and what platform?  My instinct is that this is a package/Julia versioning issue.

Comment: Julia Studio 0.4.2 on Windows 7. I tried deleting my entire package folder based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650988/julia-problems-with-adding-packages-bindeps?rq=1), but still had the same issue.

Comment: This might be a 32-bit issue. Are you using a 32-bit build or a 64-bit build?

Comment: Excellent point. I _thought_ I was using 64-bit, but I wasn't. I just installed JuliaStudio 0.4.3 64-bit, and `readtable()` seems to be working correctly now. Thanks for pointing out a bad assumption!

Comment: Glad to help. I need to get the 32-bit build to work with DataFrames. It's just a hassle to test since I haven't owned a 32-bit machine in a *long* time.

Comment: @JohnMylesWhite -- This kind of thing will always happen until we have a continuous integration server that runs every package's testsuite against 32/64-bit Linux/OSX/Windows every time either the package or Julia gets updated.

Comment: bump.  I just installed Julia version 0.2.1 (2014-1-30) i686-linux-gnu on 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 (Linux ubuntu-10-new 3.2.0-61-generic-pae) and am having the same problem.  Any suggestions/workarounds?

Comment: For what it's worth, this seems to have gone away in version 0.3.0 prerelease ...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a disappointing answer, but this problem appears to be solved in the prerelease version/with version 0.5.4 of `DataFrames`.

```
julia> versioninfo(true)
Julia Version 0.3.0-prerelease
Platform Info:
  System: Linux (i686-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8800  @ 2.66GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 32
           Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
  uname: Linux 3.2.0-61-generic-pae #92-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 1 00:10:04 UTC 2014 i686 i686

Package Directory: /home/bolker/.julia/v0.3

3 required packages:
 - DataFrames                    0.5.4
 - MixedModels                   0.3.1
 - RDatasets                     0.1.1
```